# Cannot mount a blank dvd in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, dvd

Bug on DVD/CD? With blank DVD inserted I get message that it can't be mounted... Please help...

[image: Bug dvd/cd blank...]

And want burn windows 10 to a blank cd

thank

Comment: Fortunately, a little bit annoying but that's all and bug reports - if it's really a bug - are off-topic anyway. Also you'll need a DVD or USB if you need to install it in UEFI mode. Why people still worry about optical media a day shy of 2017 beats me.

Comment: Some of us use live DVD's because they work whereas we fumble around with live USB without success. Perhaps when Ubuntu figures out how to publish a program that says "burn this ISO to USB" and it works all the time we'll join you in the good fight.

Answer (score 2):

I got this message two days ago with Ubuntu 16.04 as well. I had inserted a blank DVD in order to burn the Ubuntu 17.04 live DVD. I never had it before with Ubuntu 14.04 so I think it must have something to do with recent kernel updates on both platforms. Simply ignore the message, close the window and gburn your .ISO file to the DVD.

I can't explain why the message appears only that it is "one of those things" that happens where we "shrug our shoulders" and "move on".

Comment: Correct as far as the pop up, it's 'true',  but totally irrelevant & can be closed & ignored. Likely not kernel related, more file manager.  It's true because blank media cannot be mounted, only media with a filesystem can be mounted.

Comment: Very true it could be related to a Nautilus upgrade that effected both 14.04 and 16.04 at the same time. It's because kernels are frequently upgraded concurrently and Nautilus is infrequently upgraded that I thought the former more likely suspect than the latter.